# Troubleshooting XmlSerializer.Deserialize()

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

How does one troubleshoot/debug deserialization with XmlSerializer, i.e. XmlSerializer.Deserialize()? Is there anyway to find out why an element in the document wasn't deserialized? Or is it just trial and error?

I have a document that I am trying to deserialize and one of the properties of the target object is null after deserialization, but the element is populated in the document.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you posted an example of the code and the XML.

Answer (score 1):

If it threw an exception, the reasons would be in the InnerException. If is didn't, it probably means simply not matching layout:

- name mismatch (including case)
- namespace
- attribute vs element
- for repeated data, element vs array, and array-level

Of course a broken `set is an option too. An example of the XML and c# (for the affected data) would probably reveal all.

Comment: It did not throw an exception. It's just ignoring certain elements/properties. Will post the example when I have time later in the day. Thanks.